# html inject call function with parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

I have a problem where if i want to add a parameter to my `click` attribute then it calls the function as soon as it renders

here is my test html:

```
return html`
       <button class="menu-btn" @click="${this._OpenSubMenu(1)}>test</button>" 
`;
```

}

And the function:

```
_OpenSubMenu(test:number) {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
```

This output `Hello` as soon as the page is rendered.

So how can i avoid this while still adding a parameter to my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your function return a function.  Your click function will then execute the returned function, and due to closure's will still have access to the params.

eg..

```
_OpenSubMenu(test:number) {
  var that = this;
  return function () {
     console.log("Hello");
     //test is also a closure so you can use here
     //that will equal this
  }
}
```

If you want access to `this`, you could also use an arrow function

```
_OpenSubMenu(test:number) {
  return () => {
     console.log("Hello");
     //test is also a closure so you can use here
     //this will also still be valid here
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you response however this has a draw back i am unable to reach my properties as they are out of scope? (i.e) this.property = test

Comment: @MarcRasmussen  Yes, use the arrow function version if you want access to `this`..  If you cant use arrow functions, create a closure other `this`,..  Some people often do `var that = this` as the first line.